# How to display a matrix of tuples in MATLAB command window?

Tags: matlab, printf, tuples

For example, if:

```
a = ones(2);
b = zeros(2);
```

I need something like `display('(%d,%d)', a, b)` that displays:

```
(1,0) (1,0)
(1,0) (1,0)
```

I can do it using for loops, but I need some single-line code.

Comment: @StewieGriffin To debug my code! I want to do element-wise comparison between tens of matrices and I have to type the command a lot. They are all of same dimensions.

Comment: Why does it have to be a single line of code? Limiting yourself to a single line from the beginning creates a high  probability of confusing and unnecessarily obfuscated code. Write something that functions first, then worry about being clever.

Comment: @excaza It's not about being clever, as I said I need it as a debugging tool and I have to type it in command window with different parameters repeatedly. Maybe I should've asked about such a tool first.

Comment: Then make a [function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html)

Comment: @excaza Sure! I just though matlab may already has one..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
fun = arrayfun( @(x,y) ['(' num2str(x) ',' num2str(y) ')'], a, b, 'UniformOutput',false)
```

The result is:

```
fun = 

'(1,0)'    '(1,0)'
'(1,0)'    '(1,0)'
```

Is it OK for you?

P.S. It is really interesting what for you need this? Because there a lot of ways to compare two matrices avoiding this display.

Comment: Actually I was expecting for some simpler command, a builtin function or something.

Comment: Really I don't know such build in function. So I hope My answer is helpful for you.